# Can we say we reduced a rule if we reduced an equivalent set of smaller rules?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers, ambiguity

[image: This is the unmodified SLR(1) table]

I have constructed an SLR(1) parsing table with the following rules.

- S -> S + S + S (rule 1)
- S -> S + S (rule 2)
- S -> y

Is reducing rule 2, then shifting + and y, then again rule 2, *equivalent* to reducing rule 1? Can I claim to have reduced by rule 1, even though I did so indirectly?

Comment: Note that your grammar is ambiguous. Since SLR is a type of *deterministic* parsing it won't ever work for this grammar. Hence, isn't the question moot?

Comment: You are right. I forgot to mention I have manually resolved the conflicts. But no matter how I resolve them, it never comes to reducing rule 1. That's how this question came to be.

Comment: If you assign priority to rule 2, you'll of course never see rule 1 used so you might as well drop it. What is the purpose then; what do you want with several parse trees for the same word? Do you intend to count and/or do stochastic parsing? In that case, your shortcut won't work (consider `S + S + S + S + S + S`).

Comment: Suppose that there is a special command that the CPU supports for the addition of 3 numbers; that's the purpose of rule 1.

Comment: As you can see from the image I just uploaded, even if I assign priority to rule 1, it will never come to be reduced. If you try the input "y+y+y" you'll see it!

Comment: ad special CPU command: that should not bother you at all in the parsing phase. Such optimisations can and should be done on the AST you build during parsing.

Comment: @babou Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I just chanced on this question ... the reference @ babou will work only when I have already commented. ... Well I have seen it now (flattered you call on me, though I do not know why: competence on your previous question does not imply competence on this one), I think @Raphael gave you very sensible comments. There are many things that can be said about this, but one really has to understand what original problem you are really trying to address. Too often, question are about a solutions thought of by the user, rather than the problem he is addressing. Why do you want both rule 1 and rule 2?

Comment: @babou I've seen you give pretty good answers before, so I thought I'd ask you! :) To answer your question about wanting both rule 1 and 2, as I said, "Suppose that there is a special command that the CPU supports for the addition of 3 numbers; that's the purpose of rule 1."

Comment: So when seeing a "y+y+y" rule, it would have to be reduced with, as long as it doesn't interfere with the priority or associativity or other operators (of multiplication, division, etc.).

Comment: @Raphael did answer that. Basically, the language you define is
usually intended to express clearly what you have to say. This is
parsed into a structure, usually an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) derived
from the parse tree. Then translating into commands for the CPU is a
different problem. Usually you do not want your language to be
dependent on the machine (that is one purpose of programming
languages). So the CPU should not matter, unless you have a specific
motivation in your project, but I would have to understand it to give
you a more specific answer.

Comment: The `"y+y+y"` rule will not ne used since the `"y+y"` will be used.
Then, the parse tree or the AST can be transformed so that arguments
are reorganized by groups of 3 arguments, if that is useful. Actually,
program optimizers do things that are a lot more complicated than
that.  There is also the possibility of building several parse trees
when the grammar is ambiguous. Actually, you can even manage to use a
parser the will give preference to rule 1 whenever possible. But that
requires very different and costlier parsing techniques (dynamic programming, with
weighted grammar rules).

Comment: You can always claim "reducing rule 2, then shifting + and y, then
again rule 2, equivalent to reducing rule 1". But that is tinkering by
hand with the generated parser, which is not much different than
tinkering with the AST.

Comment: Once again you've been very helpful, thank you babou!